# testing node.js class in module

Tags: node.js, class, module, private, jasmine-node

I'm writing a node.js module and my module has a private class.

I'm trying to write tests against this class, but can't figure out how to do that.

My module looks like this

```
var main = function(get_item){
   var main_item = new MyClass(get_item);
   return main_item
}

function MyClass(item){
  this.item = item;
  return this.init();
}

MyClass.prototype = {
   init: function(){
        return find_item();
    },
   find_item: function(){
     // does a bunch of stuff to look up an item
    },
    update_item: function(){
    // does a bunch of stuff to update the item
   },
  // a bunch more methods here
}

module.exports = main

// probably turn on and off for testing
module.exports = new MyClass //??? not sure how to do this
```

Then in my spec folder I've got

```
var main = require("./modules/myClass");

describe("get item",function(){
    it("should return an item",function(){
        var item_obj = main.get_item("first_item");
        expect(item_obj.index).toBe(1);
    })
});
```

I'm guessing their is a way for me to create a new class in my spec, but I'm not sure how, or how to export the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using what you are currently doing, you would have to have

```
module.exports = { main: main, MyClass: MyClass }
```

Then use `new mymodule.MyClass` in your spec to instantiate your class. It would mean, though, that "regular" users of your class would have to do `mymodule.main("Item")` instead of `mymodule("Item")`, which changes the original interface of your module.

I have no idea if what I am about to suggest is a pattern or an anti-pattern, but here's one way to solve it:

```
module.exports = main;
module.exports.MyClass = MyClass; // only if testing
```

This was, your module's interface to regular users remains the same, and your spec can create an instance of the class by using `new mymodule.MyClass()`.